# How do I make this only print the last value?

Tags: python

I have the fallowing code to encrypt a massage:

```
massage= raw_input("Enter message to be encrypted: ")

spec = chr(0b1010101)

key = ord(spec)

encrypt = ""

for i in range(0, len(massage)):

        encrypt = encrypt + chr(ord(massage[i]) ^ key)

        print encrypt
```

say I give "yo yo" to it

it will give me :

,

,:

,:u

,:u,

,:u,:

I only need the final answer which is the ,:u,:

what do i have to do?

Comment: You should go back and accept the answers to your previous questions (click the check mark next to the correct answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the print statement outside the for loop. To do that you need to unindent the print statement.

Answer (score 3):

Put the print statement *outside the loop*.

Since the print statement is inside, it is running once per iteration. If it is outside, then it will only do it one time-- once it has finished.

```
for i in range(0, len(massage)):
    encrypt = encrypt + chr(ord(massage[i]) ^ key)

print encrypt
```

Comment: if it worked you can accept the message by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer

Comment: it says that i have to wait for 5 min in order for me to accept the message!

Answer (score 0):

unindent the call to print. This will take it out of the for loop and only print its value when the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
message= raw_input("Enter message to be encrypted: ")

spec = chr(0b1010101)

key = ord(spec)

encrypt = ""

for i in range(0, len(message)):

    encrypt = encrypt + chr(ord(message[i]) ^ key)

print encrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator:

```
message= raw_input("Enter message to be encrypted: ")
key=0b1010101
print ''.join(chr(key^ord(c)) for c in message)
```